# How can I define template to command in lua into variable?

Tags: string, lua

i'm trying to do something like that:

```
get_num_of_ones = "('1'):rep(%d)"
print(get_num_of_ones:format(24))
```

but i get the following result: `('1'):rep(24)` and not 24 times the number `1`.
how can I do it in this way so that i will get `111...11` (24 times the number 1) ?

Comment: Try `function get_num_of_ones(n) return ('1'):rep(n) end `and then `print(get_num_of_ones(24))`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest, most straightforward, efficient and readable way to achieve what you want is simply to pass your number directly to `string.rep`; there is no need to format source code here:

```lua
get_num_of_ones = ('1'):rep(24)
print(get_num_of_ones)
```

If there is the *artificial constraint* that it needs to be achieved by formatting a source code template, you need to use `load`/`loadstring`:

```lua
get_num_of_ones = "return ('1'):rep(%d)" -- you need the "return" to make it a valid chunk, and to be able to get the result out
local source = get_num_of_ones:format(24) -- formatted source code
local chunk = assert(load(source)) -- load the source code; gives us a "chunk" (function) if there was no syntax error
local retval = chunk()
print(retval)
```

Comment: can i do it in one line command ? something like: `assert(load(get_num_of_ones:format(24)))()` ?

Comment: @user123454321 yes, inlining it like that is totally fine. I only used local variables for illustration purposes.